# How To Manage User Authorization and User Access in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wanna create a feedback database and have three types of users (teacher, student, and admin) how can I do that by using ms access 2016 ?

Comment: Build a Users table. Have a 'login' process. Your question really is too broad. Do research and attempt something. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to run some VBA code on opening the Access db.  If you do not need to secure your db from meddling and just want a way to obtain different functionality I suggest you avoid Access's security, it's tricky and problematic.

If you still want that protection you can find a lot of descriptions out in Googleland, I'll describe a simple identification scheme that avoids the built-in Access id security scheme.  It does not provide any real security.

1. Establish/authenticate the user.  Easiest way is to take advantage of unique PC userids and execute Environ$("Username") to return the ID used by the PC operator to log in with.  If you cannot rely on it being unique, you may have to choose to create an initial form dialogue to set a name string.
2. Create an Access user table with all the userids/name strings plus their role (teacher, student, admin).  Look up the result of step 1 in this table.  If you don't find it put out a message about who to contact and then exit the application.  If you do find it, remember the role.
3. In your VBA code declare a userid variable and a role variable in the global context (outside all subroutine and function definitions) and make them PUBLIC.  Make sure the variable names are completely unique and do not use the same name as the module name.  Store the results of step one and step two there.

Now you can code VBA code and SQL that references both global, public variables and you do not constantly have to join a role table into everything you do.  To use the role variable in SQL, enclose the variable names in square brackets.